# How to bind array count to replace button image

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivekit

I'm trying to observe array change and bind it to the image of the button.

if the array is empty. set picture of an empty cart.

else set image of a cart.

so what I did was :

```
let x = itemsArray.observeNext { [weak self] (v) in
    let image = v.source.isEmpty ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "emptyCart") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cart")
    self?.orderItemsButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```

But if I do use this way I must dispose x in viewWillDisappear or something like that...

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: what is itemsArray here ?

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace observation with a binding. In that case disposable is handled by the framework itself (ReactiveKit).

All you need to do is this:

```
itemsArray.bind(to: self) { me, array in
    let image = array.source.isEmpty ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "emptyCart") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cart")
    me.orderItemsButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```

You can find more info about bindings in the documentation:
https://github.com/ReactiveKit/ReactiveKit#bindings

I would almost always recommend doing `bind(to:)` instead `observeNext`. It automatically handles `weak self`, disposing and also ensures that the object is updated on the correct thread.

---

As a bonus, you can also solve this problem by mapping the array signal to an image signal and then binding that to the button (assuming you are using ReactiveKit+Bond).

```
itemsArray
  .map { $0.source.isEmpty ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "emptyCart") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cart") }
  .bind(to: orderItemsButton.reactive.image)
```

Answer (score 1):

i think easy way can be something like this

```
  var itemsArray: [Any] = [] {
        didSet {
            guard oldValue != itemsArray else { return }
            let image = itemsArray.isEmpty ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "emptyCart") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cart")
            orderItemsButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

everytime you set itemsArray didSet will be called and change orderItemsButton's image if needed.

EDIT:

base on what you said in comments you can use delegate

```
protocol CartDelegate: class {
    func setCartImage(isEmpty: Bool)
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, CartDelegate {

    var orderItemsButton: UIButton!
    var someRandomClass: SomeRandomClass!

    func setCartImage(isEmpty: Bool) {
        if isEmpty {
            // set image to empty cart
            orderItemsButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        } else {
            // set image to full cart
            orderItemsButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // initate and set delegate to self
        someRandomClass = SomeRandomClass()
        someRandomClass.delegate = self
    }
}


class SomeRandomClass {
    weak var delegate: CartDelegate?

    var itemsArray: [Any] = [] {
        didSet {
            delegate?.setCartImage(isEmpty: itemsArray.isEmpty)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `itemsArray` declared in a different class.. not in my view controller

Comment: @MarryG then you need delegation to solve this problem. im gonna update whole answer for you